jwt-auth redirect to home instead of 403
I;m using laravel 10.10 and tymon/jwt-auth library.
I have some routes that need to be auth token and some of my routes don't need it (for example to get cities api).
I want to show 403 status header code when the user needs a token and it's expired.
but I don't know why my Postman shows the home page when my token expires.
web.php
Route::get('/', function () {
   dd("my text appear when user not login or expired token");
  
})->name('home');

api.php
Route::prefix('/v1')->group(function () {
    Route::prefix('/auth')->group(function () {
        Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('v1.auth.login');
        Route::post('/verify', [AuthController::class, 'verify'])->name('v1.auth.verify');
        Route::post('/me', [AuthController::class, 'me'])->name('v1.auth.me');
    });

my AuthController.php
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['only' => ['logout', 'refreshToken', 'me']]);

    }


config/auth.php
<?php

return [

 

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

  

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_reset_tokens',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

   

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];

my kernel.php:
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use App\Http\Middleware\AlgoAuthentication;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array<int, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
       // AlgoAuthentication::class,
        //\App\Http\Middleware\CheckAuthMiddleware::class
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array<string, array<int, class-string|string>>
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,

        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's middleware aliases.
     *
     * Aliases may be used instead of class names to conveniently assign middleware to routes and groups.
     *
     * @var array<string, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $middlewareAliases = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'precognitive' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\HandlePrecognitiveRequests::class,
        'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        //'isAdmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckAuthMiddleware::class
    ];
}

my libraries:
    "php": "^8.1",
    "flugger/laravel-responder": "^3.3",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
    "hekmatinasser/verta": "^8.3",
    "intervention/image": "*",
    "kavenegar/laravel": "^1.3",
    "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
    "laravel/ui": "^4.2",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
    "predis/predis": "^2.2",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "^2.1",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables": "10.0",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-export": "^10.1",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-html": "10.0"

where is my problem?
